# Default resizing Split View to not blur one window

Tags: macos, fullscreen, split-view

In OS X El Capitan, Apple introduced a feature called "[Split View](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204948)" that allows you to put two fullscreen apps side by side. Normally when you click and drag the middle dividing line one of the two apps will blur. If you hold <kbd>Option</kbd> while moving the divider neither window will blur.

How can I make this the default behavior, so I don't have to hold <kbd>Option</kbd> when resizing?

Comment: Thanks man, didn't even know there was a way to disable the blur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resizing windows in split view no longer blurs one window as of macOS Catalina.